# scanf and switch statement debug

Tags: c, algorithm, switch-statement, scanf

All the cases work except the switch 'a' case. The a case runs the insert method below. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. printf statements inside the switch statement don't work.

````
void insert() {
        char name;
        printf("enter your name");
        scanf("%c", &name);
        for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
            if (!Thesame(names[1], name) == 0 && counter != LENGTH && strlen(name) <= MAX){
                for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++){
                strcpy(names[counter],name);
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("error");
            }
        }
    ```
    int main() {
    
        while (1) {
    
            char input;
    
            printf("Type in 'a' be added to the system \n");
            printf("Type in 'n' to print next patient and remove from 
            waitlist \n");
            printf("Type in 'l' to list the patients on the waitlist \n");
            printf("Type in 'q' to quit the program \n");
            scanf("%c", &input);
    
    
            switch (input) {
    
                case 'a':
                    insert();
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    next();
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    print();
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    return 0;
    
            }
        }
    }
````

Comment: A very easy way for you to debug this on your own is to add in prints to see where something goes wrong. Putting in prints inside the insert function to see if it enters trough all of the if conditions will help you find where the issue is and then you can ask/search for more specific questions.

Comment: If you have typed in a string in response to `char name; printf("enter your name"); scanf("%c", &name);` all but the first character will remain in the input buffer to be used elsewhere. You can't apply `strlen(name)` as the compiler will tell you.

Comment: regarding: `printf("error");`. always end the format string with `'\n'` so the data is immediately output to the terminal.  Otherwise the data sits in the `stdout` stream buffer until some 'triggering' even happens, like the buffer overflowing or a '\n' is output or a input statement is executed or the program ends

Comment: regarding; `printf("Type in 'a' be added to the system \n");
            printf("Type in 'n' to print next patient and remove from 
            waitlist \n");
            printf("Type in 'l' to list the patients on the waitlist \n");
            printf("Type in 'q' to quit the program \n");
            scanf("%c", &input);`  1) only call `printf()` once, with each string separated by white space.  2) the 'wrapped' string will fail to compile.  the call to `scanf()` format string needs a leading space to consume any leftover '\n', etc

Comment: OT: the `switch()` statement needs a `default` case for when the user does not input one of the 4 expected characters.

Comment: what are you expecting: `if (!Thesame(names[1], name) == 0` to perform?

Comment: this function: `Thesame()` is called, but is not posted.  How are we to know what it does?

Comment: we do not know what `print()`, `next()` and `Thesame()` do, can you post more code? we are unable to solve this problem as it is

Answer (score 1):

`char name;`: `name` can contain only a single character. So when you type for example: `cuq`, `name` will contain `c`, then `insert` does whatever with `name` and then returns to `main`. Then in `main` `scanf("%c", &input)` will read the remaining characters from the input buffer ('u' and 'q') and because of `case 'q':` the programs stops. Use a debugger or put some printfs at strategic places in your code to see what happens.

You want a string here and you probably want something like this in `insert`:

```
char name[100];
printf("enter your name: ");
scanf("%s", name);
...
```

You also probably need to change the `Thesame` function.

Comment: to avoid a possible buffer overflow, replace: `scanf("%s", &name);` with: `scanf("%99s", name);`   Note: a bare reference to an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, so don't use the `&` on the array name